# how to code one vs rest multi class SVM for action recognition project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv3.0

I'm new to SVM. I want to use Multiclass svm for classification in my action recognition project. My data set have 15 class like running jogging walking biking etc. I understand binary SVM and seen lot of examples. I'm getting confusion in one vs one multiclass svm and one vs rest multiclass svm.

My question is: Should I have to create and train a svm for each class like svm1  for running, svm2 for jogging.....etc what should be class lebels for each created svm either (0,1,2,.......14) or (0,1). how to determine the model for multiclass classification.how the result will be predicted ?

I was trying some thing like this:

```
Mat trainData, trainLabels;

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
        {
        sprintf_s(filename, "VocabularyHOG/Dictionary%d.yml", i);
        Mat feature;
        FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::READ);
        fs["vocabulary"] >> feature;
        feature.convertTo(feature, CV_32F); // make sure we got float data
        trainData.push_back(feature.reshape(1, 1)); // as a flat column
        trainLabels.push_back(i); // the classlabel
}

// Train the SVM
Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setKernel(SVM::LINEAR);
svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6));
svm->train(trainData, ROW_SAMPLE, trainLabels);
     Mat testData;
 FileStorage fs("DictionaryrunningHOG.yml", FileStorage::READ);
    fs["vocabulary"] >> testData;
    int response = svm->predict(testData.reshape(1, 1));
    if (response == 1)
        cout << "boxing";
    else
        cout << "negative result";

    waitKey(27);
    return 0;
```

but getting error. what is wrong here?? how to code one vs rest multiclass svm properly.What is the label for each svm? Thanks

Comment: _"but getting error."_ What error exactly? [Add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54165190/edit) that information to your question please!

Comment: during debug crash at line trainData.push_back(feature.reshape(1, 1));...i'm doing any thing wrong in programming please suggest.